# ARMv8 Assembly Compiler Error for beginner

Tags: gcc, armv8, fedora-28

I've been trying to get this simple ARMv8 assembly code to compile. I've followed the examples of the instructor for my course, but I still can't manage to get it to compile.

I have a duplicate of the instructors code, and according to the lecture slides, all that I should need to type into the console is "gcc demo1.s -g -o demo1"

However, when I type this command into terminal, I am presented with two error codes that I cannot manage to resolve.

```
   .global main
```

main:

```
    MOV     x19,    10
    ADD     x19,    x19,    -10

    RET
```

demo1.s:5: Error: too many memory references for 'mov'

demo1.s:6: Error: too many memory references for 'add'

Comment: Your code does compile fine. What is the output for the following command:  `gcc --verbose` , and more specifically what do you have after `Target:` in this output ? I would have `Target: aarch64-linux-gnu` on my system.

Comment: Did you solve your issue ?

Comment: Yeah, turns out the reason was because my ssh parameters were misconfigured, so I ended up trying to compile the code on a Linux-based server instead of an ARM-based server.